# _.debounce and Iron.controller() in eventmap

Tags: javascript, meteor, underscore.js, iron-router, lodash

I want to implement a debounced search with iron-router where the search query is written into the controllers state. unfortunately the only way I could get _.debounce to work is to pass it directly to the event map like so:

```js
Template.search.events({
  'keydown #search': _.debounce(function(event) {
    var controller = Iron.controller();
   }, 750)
});
```

unfortunately Iron.controller() doesn't know the context here so an error drops.

But if I nest the debounce inside a function to get the Iron.controller(), _.debounce never fires.

```js
Template.search.events({
  'keydown #search': function(event) {
    var state = Iron.controller().state;
    var q = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    _.debounce(function() {
      state.set("q", q);
    }, 750);
  }
});
```

Has anybody done something similar and a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `debounce`, but if I'm not mistaking, the following should work:

```js
var doIt = _.debounce(function(func){
    func()
}, 750);

Template.search.events({
  'keydown #search': function(event) {
    var state = Iron.controller().state;
    var q = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    doIt(function(){
        state.set("q", q);
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: But why does this work and my examples didn't? Why do you have to transfer the _.debounce into another function?

Comment: `_debounce(func)` is a wrapper, it returns a function. So what you are doing in the second example is generate a wrapped function... But you never execute it. In your first example, you assigned the wrapped function to a property (which works), and in this answer Peppe L-G assigned it to a variable and then executed it. Thus, you could too do it by changing the syntax a bit in your second example, or placing it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that iron-router uses a fair amount of bare `this` [throughout the code](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/ca9db075a81b362399ec56d531bb93a525f9c7fe/lib/router_client.js#L152).

Perhaps the scope is not correctly set when you debounce the event handler. If this is the case, you could try binding it to `this`:

```
Template.search.events({
  'keydown #search': _.debounce(function(event) {
    var controller = Iron.controller();
   }.bind(this), 750)
});
```

Maybe it should be bond to `events`. I'm not sure, as I'm not familiar with this library.

As for the second example, as Peppe L-G correctly suggests it, `debounce` works by returning a *debounced function*. In your example, you never call it!

```
a = function(){};
b = _.debounce(a, 200);
a() // immediate
b() // waits 200 millis, calls a()
```

Also, it's important to notice that you should not **declare** the debounced function inside the event handler. Otherwise, you'll always create a new debounced function and all of them will fire at the first opportunity, defeating the purpose.

I recommend you name your debounced handler more appropriately. For example:

```
var handleKeydownEventDebounced = _.debounce(function(controller, query){
    controller.state.set("q", query);
}, 750);

Template.search.events({
  'keydown #search': function(event) {
    handleKeydownEventDebounced(Iron.controller(), $(event.currentTarget).val());
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately your first example doesn't work:
Uncaught Error: There is no current view
The debounced function by Peppe L-G was the right choice